# Setting ID3 "album artist" to be equal to "artist - album" combined

Tags: linux, script, music, id3

I tried to do it with EasyTAG but it doesn't seem to be possible. I'm going to create a big compilation of music and every song is from different artist and album.

Answer (score 0):

## How do I set 'album artist' ID3 Tag in EasyTAG (etc)

You may have missed the tagging option in the EasyTAG scanner:

[image: EasyTAG tag and filename scan]

where `%z` refers to the album artist. If your files are appropriately structured, the album and artist can be combined this way.

### Other Options

#### Picard

It is also possible to do this by using the scripting capabilities of [MusicBrainz Picard](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/):

[image: MusicBrainz Picard script tagger screenshot]

Access the tagger script via `Options → Options → Advanced → Scripting`. You can find [more information and examples in the scripting guide](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/docs/scripting).

#### eyeD3

[eyeD3](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/) is an ID3 tag manipulator written in python.

> eyeD3 is a Python tool for working with audio files, specifically mp3 files containing ID3 metadata (i.e. song info).

The CLI tool *doesn't* include a flag to write the 'album artist' tag (though it can read it).

However, it is exposed via its python [library](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/api/eyed3.html?highlight=album%20artist#eyed3.core.Tag.album_artist):

> class eyed3.core.Tag
>
> An abstract interface for audio tag (meta) data (e.g. artist, title, etc.)
>
> `read_only = False`
>
> `artist`
>
> `album_artist`
>
> `album`